# Web page button error

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have created a web page using `VB 2010`, i used Master page and i dont put any session, cookies or anything that can affect the website. But when i create a 'submit button' on any of the child page, i goes to an error stating the underline -

```
Server Error in '/EP-CMS' Application.
```

The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

```
Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ep-cms\ae3f1090\4636a7bf\App_Web_2wkxnfol.4.cs    Line: 0
```

Stack Trace:

```
    [FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a     
   non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a 
   non-white space character  among the padding characters. ]   
     .............................etc, etc.,
```

I dont know why, i have changed the submit button to image button, etc,. but after clicking the button it always points to this error. Linking page was fine but even if i dont write anything on the button events (simply putting button) it leads to this error.. Why

Comment: can you show some code where you handle the button?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either you don't have permission to write in temp folder or your reference files are not located in your local machine.

Try following solution.

1. Check if you can open the location

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ep-cms

Also check %temp% is accessible and you have write permission for that folder and also can write permission from the user you are running the application..

1. If still not working Clean your solution and delete everything from
   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ep-cms\ae3f1090\4636a7bf\
   folder and then rebuild the solution.
2. Also check by re-registering your ASP.Net framework by running following command from command prompt with Administrative rights

aspnet_regiis -i

and re-perform the step 2.

Please feedback the same if you are able to solve using these methods or not. Try step 1 and 2 first.

Comment: NO. it doesnt work, but i have figured it now, i modified an existing one that my outgoing friend have created. There is a statements (underline) that he put on the Masterpage, i dont even know how it works but ive removed it and it work fine now. Thank you..